# How can I stop the ding when hitting enter? (Handled and SuppressKeyEvent ARE true)

Tags: c#, winforms

Yes, I know there are already posts about this but they all are missing either the setting of Handled to true or SuppressKeyPress to true.  My code does, but it STILL dings!  Driving me nuts:

```
private void query_KeyDown(object sender,KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Enter) return;
  if (query.Text.Trim() == "") return;

  e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  MessageBox.Show("test");
}
```

Any idea how to fix it?  Yes, the notation is "weird" stacking them that way and just to be 100% sure I also tried it setting true for each individual one on their own line but it made no difference (as it should not).

I assume I am having a brain fart and missing something simple, but I cannot figure out what.  Thanks!

Comment: `if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter) { e.SuppressKeyPress = true; }`

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and it isn't working.  It still dings when I suppress key press.

Comment: That is not what you're doing.

Comment: Yea, I'm returning on a negative condition instead of operating on a positive but that is irrelevant.  Also yes, I'm stacking handled with suppress but also that's irrelevant, and as I mentioned I also (just to be 100% sure) separated them and it had no effect.

Comment: You don't have to *separate* anything. Use just the code I posted.

Comment: That made no difference.

Comment: Remove *everything* from that handler, than use just that code.

Comment: But to what end?  The function would do nothing.  What good is that?  I need it to throw a messagebox, and once I add that it dings.  However, I ended up fixing it by just moving it to a keypress instead of keydown.

Comment: There's a "ding" when you hit enter??  Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: Go into a Windows form, click a single line textbox and press enter.  You'll get a noise because you can't multiline in a single line textbox.

In retrospect, yea, I didn't put enough detail in the original post.  I forgot not everyone knows to what I refer, oops.  It's resolved though.